# How to convert string to a variable in IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, strings

I have the following string "CreatePipe" and I want to convert it to a variable so I can use `x` to find all its references:
[image]

How can I do it? I am not sure what to choose here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to type `A` on the string.